# CommonsMultipartResolver messing up binary encoding

Tags: spring, http, encoding, apache-commons, multipartform-data

I'm trying to save a binary file uploaded with a  `multipart/mixed` HTTP request that arrives to my controller as a `@RequestPart ByteArrayResource`, but when I save the byte array to disk with `FileOutputStream.write` the bytes are different from the ones in the original file.

Since the bytes corresponding to ASCII characters are the same and the ones that differ are the ones with higher values, I assumed it was a matter of character encoding, but setting

```
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
```

for the `CommonsMultipartResolver` doesn't solve the issue.

The request part also has `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`, but still it looks like Commons' multipart resolver is injecting in the `ByteArrayResource` bytes that aren't exactly the same as the ones sent by the client.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your part specify `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Yep. In the end I solved it bypassing the CommonsMultipartResolver, passing the whole `HttpServletRequest` to my controller method and parsing parts inside it, but I still don't understand why the resolver changed the encoding inside the request and how to have it preserved.

Comment: That is some serious bug if you had `application/octet-stream` present and at no point you worked with it as with character stream (Reader / Writer). Commons-multipart is heavily used library, it would be strange if it contains such bug. Are you sure you were using commons-multipart? I know that e.g. Tomcat had some problems with Servlet 3 multipart support. If your configuration was not correct so that commons-multipart was not really used, that might be the issue.

Comment: AFAIK Spring uses it by default, and I haven't changed its configuration, but you're right, I haven't checked in detail to be sure that Commons-multipart is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved it by manually parsing the request parts:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);            
for(FileItem item : items) {                     
switch(item.getFieldName()) {
       //Do something with each of the single parts
    }
}
```

Not exactly the cleanest way, but at least I got it working.